# Installing Red Hat 6.4 (RHEL 6.4) cannot find installation media

Tags: installation, operating-systems, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to install RHEL 6.4 on a Dell PowerEdge R720. I am using a DVD and every time the Red Hat prompt comes up and asks for my language and keyboard preference. After that, an error message comes up saying that no installation media could be found in any of my CD drives. No idea why it is doing that and really need to get this system set up.

Comment: Have you checked the `md5sum` of the downloaded iso? Is it the same as that listed on the RedHat webpage? If this is not a downloaded .iso, please update your question.